# Not able to use functions inside of a own created Angular "library"

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

So I am trying to create a separate module in Angular that would hold functions that I use frequently in all of my controllers.

Right now I have made a file `common.js.coffee` which contains the module that I created to hold my functions.

It looks like this:

```
@test.factory 'MyLib', ['$window', ($window) ->

    flashNotification = ($scope, text) ->
        console.log("Here")
        $scope.message = text
        $scope.notify = true
        setTimeout(() ->
            $scope.notify = false
        , 2000)
]
```

And now when I try to use it in my controller like this:

```
@test.controller 'UsersCtrl',
    ['$scope', '$location', '$http', 'MyLib',
    ($scope, $location, $http, MyLib) ->

        $scope.users = []
        $scope.roles = []
        $scope.notify = false

        $scope.updateUser = (user, selectedRole) ->
            $http({
                method: 'PATCH',
                url:    './users/' + user.id + '.json',
                data:   user: {role: selectedRole.key}
            }).success( (data) ->
                for user in $scope.users
                    if user.id == data.user.id
                        user.role = data.user.role
                        # Here I call the Common function
                        MyLib.flashNotification($scope, 'Updated role for user: ' + user.name)
            ).error( ->
                # Display error notification
            )
]
```

But now when my controller tries to execute this function that I have made into the factory called MyLib, it say's that the function is not even declared yet.

Comment: I don't use coffeescript but as I understand it it automatically returns the last item in scope? So you're currently returning the method (flashNotification) itself, rather than a factory object to which the method is attached. If that's true you should be able to confirm by calling `MyLib($scope)` in the controller. That should work, though you'll likely want to change it

Comment: You are correct, it is indeed returning the first function in it only. But how could I change this behavior?

Comment: Convert factory to service, it should work as is

Comment: @harish will it? It's still returning a single method so im not sure how. Kaspar: in plain JS you would `return { method: function(){...} }`, so the coffee equivalent of that I guess

Comment: Okay will see what I can do.

Comment: Still seems to be no luck. Making it into service does not work and returning the function also does not work. But with the latter i am not 100% sure as it's not really how it's meant to be done in coffescript. Just writing a function like I shows in my question should allready be a return it self.

Comment: It is a return, but you either need to a return an object with that method attached in the case of a factory, or assign the method to `this` and return `this` in the case of a service. The docs on both are pretty clear from a js point of view, I can't imagine it's hard to create an object in coffeescript and return it

Comment: Thank you, got it working. The syntax for it looks a bit weird in coffeescript but atleast it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by making the syntax look like this:

```
@test.factory 'MyLib', ['$window', ($window) ->

    {
        flashNotification: ($scope, text) ->
            console.log("Here")
            $scope.message = text
            $scope.notify = true
            setTimeout(() ->
                $scope.notify = false
            , 2000)

    }


]
```